# Django: ImportError: No module named 'scipy.sparse.base'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, scipy

For my project I am using Scipy, but as it seems, my project has trouble in importing stuff from it.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f2f4244f400>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 673, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/betaros/PycharmProjects/nsg-lfp/webFrontEnd/webFrontEnd/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    url(r'^pass_list/', include('pass_list.urls')),
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 673, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/betaros/PycharmProjects/nsg-lfp/webFrontEnd/pass_list/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/betaros/PycharmProjects/nsg-lfp/webFrontEnd/pass_list/views.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pass_eval_universal as pe
  File "/home/betaros/PycharmProjects/nsg-lfp/logfile_lib/source/pass_eval_universal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "/home/betaros/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 228, in <module>
    from .base import *
ImportError: No module named 'scipy.sparse.base'
```

I am using Debian 9 with Python 3.5.3 and PyCharm Community 2017.1.4. I installed the following packages successful with pip for Python 3:

```
Django
XlsxWriter
appdirs
configparser
cycler
django-floppyforms
django-tables2
matplotlib
numpy
packaging
pip
pyparsing
python-dateutil
pytz
scikit-learn
scipy
setuptools
six
sklearn
```

If I forgot somethink feel free to ask. Every help is apprechiated.

Comment: how are you using it? can you post that

Comment: can your try if an `import scipy` statement works?

Comment: @darthvader1996 just writing `import scipy` works, but running an example [SciPy Getting Started](https://www.scipy.org/getting-started.html) creates the same error. Looks like somethink is wrong with my scipy install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your scipy install was messed up. I had faced a similar issue earlier, and solved it like this:

First remove python scipy by doing:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-scipy
```

Then reinstall it using `apt-get` as a python package like, `sudo apt-get install python-scipy` and then doing a `pip install scipy`.

Comment: If it happens under Mac OS?